# Does the limit of a series of functions with large zero sets have a large zero set?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, roots

Let $(f_k)$ be a sequence of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfying these two conditions:

- It converges uniformly to a limit $f$.
- For every $k$ the zero set $f^{-1}_k(0)$ is uncountable.

Does it follow that $f^{-1}(0)$ is uncountable?

This is not true if the compact interval is replaced with the whole real line.
Just let $C$ be a compact uncountable set and define $f_k(x)=\tanh(d(x-k,C))$.
The zero sets are $k+C$ but the limit function is $f\equiv1$.
I imagine compactness could help, but I have found no proof or counterexample.
Perhaps the sets $f^{-1}_k(0)$ can be shown to converge in a suitable way as $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; define $$f_k(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &:0\leq x\leq 1/k\\ x-\frac{1}{k} &: 1/k\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}.$$

This converges uniformly to $f(x)=x$, for every $k$, the set $f_k^{-1}(0)$ is uncountable, but $f^{-1}(0)=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for too complicated counterexamples.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Not a problem, getting caught up in complicated counterexamples is an easy pitfall a lot of people (including myself most of the time!) fall into.